# PHPUnit live log on failure/error

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I've been running a few thousand phpunit tests recently. I use `--process-isolation` option so it takes some 40 minutes for tests to complete.

Sometimes after an aggressive refactoring a lot of tests start failing (thanks God I have the tests !). And if a test fails in the middle of a test suite then I have to wait 20 more minutes to see what test it is and it's message.

I would use `--stop-on-failure` if didn't interrupt the whole process. Basically I'm looking for `--log-on-failure` option.

What I'm looking for exactly is some way to see the fail/error message of the test right after it failed and not after all other tests are finished. But the whole process of other tests execution should not be interrupted. Logging to a file will suffice as well.

I'll appreciate your suggestions.

EDIT: I'm glad to see your suggestions how I could improve my testing in general and I will try to follow them, however I would like to find a solution to my exact problem.

Comment: have you tried `--verbose`?

Comment: What info does it provide ? I used --debug which provides info about the each test case and data provider data set. It outputs too much info. I'd like to get information about the failed tests only.

Comment: I think this question is still not properly answered. If anyone knows. Please share!

Answer (score 2):

Even if you neglegt it, you are looking for `--stop-on-failure`.

Because when you see where the error is, you can write the fix. Then you need to run the tests again.

If you would only log on failure, you could not yet run the tests again because let's say after 10 seconds the first failure is visible and fixed within another minute. However you still need to wait ca. 38 minutes until you can run the tests.

Also the other problem you have is that your tests are taking too long. You need to get them faster. That you're using `--process-isolation` is eventually a sign that you have integration tests. Separate those from your unit-tests, they often take longer.

Then you can run the integration tests in isolation and continuously (in a loop, always) and you run the unit-tests when you save your files.

Comment: Imagine the following situation, for example 3 tests fail after 10 minutes, 5 after 20 minutes and 2 after 30 minutes. When you see the first 3 failed tests you want to start working on them right away even if the whole process suite hasn't finished yet. Very often trivial mistakes like the wrong variable name, type, etc happen. It could happen that by the time you see the next 5 failed tests you've already finished fixing the first 3. If the --stop-on-failure was used you would spent the time again. Moreover, you would not be aware of other fails.

Comment: You're right, most of the tests are integration test which heavily rely on the DB. That's why the DB is dropped and reinitialized on each test startUp. I'll consider the idea of separating the pure unit tests from integration tests though. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: Running tests after saving the files ? The tests must finish in seconds. Have you this system implemented ? If yes could you please tell more about it.

Comment: Unittest should only take seconds - fraction of seconds. With integration tests this is not always possible. You write you're using a database. Ensure the integration test database is in memory only, not on disk. That should give you some more speed for the integration tests. Group as SDC lined out, you can also do that by having different subdirectories, on for unit-tests, one for integration-tests.

Comment: Yes, you are correct about storing the data in memory. I mounted a tmpfs partition in the RAM and had mysql store it's files there. It gave me a boost from 70 minutes to 39.

Comment: Speaking of running pure unit tests on file save. Could you give more hints about this ?

Comment: That normally works with your IDE or with your shell. Most easy is within the shell and the `watch` command - put the shell window on your second monitor, preferable with color. It will automatically run your tests, if you break something, you will notice. However, separate your integration tests from the unit tests at first.

Answer (score 1):

good on you for writing all those tests. As you say, they can prove their worth quickly when you start a big refactoring task! But 40 minutes sounds like a very slow set of tests, even for a few thousand of them -- I've got several hundred running in around 10 seconds. Perhaps you've got some tests that are particularly slow?

If your system suits doing so, it might be worth splitting them out into groups, so that you can set it to only run tests that are relevant to the code that's being changed. PHPUnit supports grouping of tests, and specifying on the command-line which groups to run.

This could be a particularly effective strategy if most of your tests are pretty fast but you have a handful of very slow tests that take up most of the time. If you can get it to skip a few of the really slow tests when they're not relevant, it'll make a big difference.

Furthermore, this strategy of grouping the tests also allows you to use `--stop-on-failure` for each group, while still being able to run all the tests in the other groups.

See the [PHPUnit manual for more information on grouping tests](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.group).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Most of the tests are integration tests that work with the real DB. DB is cleaned and filled with data on each test startup.
I'm aware of test grouping and of course I run the relevant tests before running the whole suit. In my opinion one of the best things of the integration tests is that they test everything not only what you've directly changed and find hard to find mistakes which are often found by the end users.

Comment: I'll think about the more fine grained grouping though.